# two background inside one tag

Tags: html, css

How can I give background both side just inside `<h3> tag`

```
<h3>heading goes here</h3>
```

As below:

```
+---+--------------------------+------+
|>>>+ heading goes here        |<<<   +
+---+--------------------------+------+
```

Like this?

```
h3{
background: url('path') no-repeat left center;
background: url('path') no-repeat right center;
}
```

**update**

---

Okay, I used like this one:

```
#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3 {
    background: url(../images/icon-news.jpg)no-repeat center left;
    position: relative;
}
#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3:after{
    background: url("../images/icon-news.jpg") no-repeat right center;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

but the same background-image used in `:after` pseudo is not showing.

Comment: Don't you know already you have to show us what you've tried? Read [Multiple Backgrounds with CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as this:

```
h3{
background: url('path') no-repeat left center, 
url('path') no-repeat right center;
}
```

> **url separated by a comma.**

[see this url for different browser compatiblity before you use multiple backgrounds](http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds)

**As per your update**

If you use `:after pseudo` element you should also define the width and height of the image you have like this:

```
#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3 {
    background: url(../images/icon-news.jpg)no-repeat center left;
    position: relative;
}
#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3:after{
    background: url("../images/icon-news.jpg") no-repeat right center;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You should add a note about browser compatibility. A couple of web-sites mention that it does not work on IE 8 or lower. A lot of people, especially large companies are still using IE 8.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways to achieve multiple backgrounds using CSS.

You can use the **:before and :after pseudo-elements** ([tutorial with code](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/)).

```
h3 {
  position: relative;
}
h3:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 10px;
   background: #4aa929;
}
h3:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; right: 10px;
   background: #fff;
}
```

Or you can use the **multiple backgrounds feature of CSS3** ([tutorial with code](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)).

```
h3 {
    background: url('path') no-repeat left center, 
                url('path') no-repeat right center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Itay. I simplified the example.

Comment: You should add a note about browser compatibility on the second example. A couple of web-sites mention that it does not work on IE 8 or lower. A lot of people, especially large companies are still using IE 8.